# Using the After and Hover together in CSS

Tags: css

In order to show links that go to an external page, I have a little gif that goes after the text, using the after property of css.

```
.[style]:after{content:url(../images/main/externallink.gif)}
```

The problem is when it comes to making the image change (to change the colour) on roll-over; the following code works fine but adds the image to the first one instead of changing it!

```
.[style] a:hover:after{content:url(../images/main/externallinkover.gif)}
```

Can anyone suggest a way to make the original 'after' image disappear, or suggest a completely different way of doing this?

Comment: there's a space between .[style] and the a:hover?

Comment: What if `a:hover, a:after` ..

Comment: In one statement you have `.[style]:after` and in the second you have `.[style] a:hover:after`. They are not following the same structure and so will not match the same element in two different states.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're applying the hover image to a different element than the initial image.

If you apply both images to the link, you should get the behaviour you want:

```
.[style] a:after{content:url(../images/main/externallink.gif)}

.[style] a:hover:after{content:url(../images/main/externallinkover.gif)}
```

(Query: I take it `.[style]` isn't the actual selector you're using?)

Comment: Great - that's worked perfectly, thanks.

(And no, I wasn't actually calling my style '[style]'!)

Comment: @MattBowyer: hurray! Sure - `[style]` is a bit of a confusing way to write it, because it's actually a CSS selector (specifically, [the attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#matching-attrs)).